# How can I get duplicate rows that have different values in another field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling a little bit with improving this query:

```
SELECT
    pm.miembro_documento, COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    PostulantesMiembros pm 
GROUP BY 
    miembro_documento 
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This query is showing me the people in PostulantesMiembros whose identification (miembro_documento) is 2 times or more (repeated registers) like so:

| miembro_documento | count |
| --- | --- |
| 71850071 | 2 |

now for your understanding of what I wish to do, if I search by the identification (miembro_documento) in PostulantesMiembros, by for example the 71850071 you can see on the table, I get this result:

| miembro_id | miembro_nombres | miembro_documento | miembro_postulante |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27224 | Roberto | 71850071 | 8283 |
| 29658 | Roberto | 71850071 | 9042 |

As you can see the same person is here 2 times, which means in the context of the application that he has 2 certificates associated to him, having this in mind now there is a column in PostulantesMiembros that is called "`miembro_postulante`", this column is the foreign key to the table "`Postulantes`" which primary key is "`postulante_id`", this table is the certificates, here in Postulantes there is a field called "`postulante_postulacion_fecha`" which is the date of the asignation/opening of the certificate, now what I wish to do is to get the registers that are duplicated by member document in `PostulantMembers` (this is what the query at the begining of question is doing) but also have the same date (`postulante_postulacion_fecha`) in `Postulantes` (this second condition is what im struggling to achieve), because I want to see if apart from being duplicated because he opened or got asigned 2 certificates, it got done on the same date, to check if this is possible to happen or has happened before.

What I have tried is:

```
SELECT
    pm.miembro_documento, p.postulante_postulacion_fecha, 
    COUNT(*)  
-- tables we need
FROM 
    PostulantesMiembros pm, Postulantes p
-- the relationship between the tables, I'm not sure if this AND is doing something (Postulantes does not have member_document field)
WHERE 
    pm.miembro_postulante = p.postulante_id 
    AND pm.miembro_documento = pm.miembro_documento
    -- I though that by doing p.postulante_postulacion_fecha = p.postulante_postulacion_fecha I would get registers that also had same date but not working
    AND p.postulante_postulacion_fecha = p.postulante_postulacion_fecha
GROUP BY 
    pm.miembro_documento, p.postulante_postulacion_fecha 
HAVING  
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

An expected result would be:

| miembro_documento | postulante_postulacion_fecha | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 71850071 | 2007-04-27 00:00:00.000 | 2 |

Here I could see the member document that is reapeated and the date of both certifications (this date is the same in both certifications)

So for this expected result to happen, I think that the data in `Postulantes` table should be like this for example:

| postulante_id | postulante_postulacion_fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 8283 | 2007-04-27 00:00:00.000 |
| 9042 | 2007-04-27 00:00:00.000 |

And on `PostulantesMiembros` table, it should look like this:

| miembro_id | miembro_nombres | miembro_documento | miembro_postulante |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27224 | Roberto | 71850071 | 8283 |
| 29658 | Roberto | 71850071 | 9042 |

I would appreciate alot any help, please tell me if you need any more context or have any questions

**EDIT (I will try to explain what is wrong with the current query, it is bringing valid results (like the desired one above this EDIT), but also not valid results like the ones im going to explain):**

The query is bringing results like this:

| miembro_documento | postulante_postulacion_fecha | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 71290588 | 2002-07-30 00:00:00.000 | 2 |

But when I check how this data looks in PostulantesMiembros (Serch by miembro_documento 71290588):

| miembro_id | miembro_nombres | miembro_documento | miembro_postulante |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27224 | David | 71850071 | 4355 |
| 29658 | Lilibeth | 71850071 | 4355 |

And in Postulantes it looks like this:

| postulante_id | postulante_postulacion_fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 4355 | 2002-07-30 00:00:00.000 |

As you can see I have David and Lilibeth, yes both with the same identification number (miembro_documento), and thats not the problem with the query (you could also imagine that both registers have the name David if you want), but the problem is that the I need it to only show results if the `miembro_postulante` column is different, like lets suppose David has 4355, then Lilibeth should have 4356, for me to then check at Postulantes and find out that `postulante_postulacion_fecha` is the same on both 4356 and 4355. If they both have the same `miembro_postulante` then this is not going to be useful... I hope I explained myself well, feel free to ask for more input.

**What is expected?? For it to be a valid result**, then when searching by `miembro_documento` on `PostulantesMiembros` 71290588, I should see something like this:

| miembro_id | miembro_nombres | miembro_documento | miembro_postulante |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27224 | David | 71850071 | 4355 |
| 29658 | Lilibeth | 71850071 | 4356 |

Notice `miembro_postulante` is different, and then when searching at Postulantes table with id 4355, and then with id 4356, I should find out that they both have the same `postulante_postulacion_fecha` (Date):

| postulante_id | postulante_postulacion_fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 4355 | 2002-07-30 00:00:00.000 |

| postulante_id | postulante_postulacion_fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 4356 | 2002-07-30 00:00:00.000 |

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Also, the `HAVING` should **only** be applied to conditions on **aggregated columns**  - so for the `COUNT(*) > 1`, it's correct - but the other condition should be in the `WHERE` clause - not the `HAVING` (and it **really** should be in the `JOIN` condition between the two tables, to be the best solution)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will keep them in mind

Comment: Sample data and expected results as text (not images) would help immensely

Comment: @Charlieface Hmm not sure if this can help but for example the expected result would be: in the query at the begining that is returning the person Roberto with document 71850071, I want the query to check if the certifications (miembro_postulante) 8282 and 9042 (this 2 numbers are the primary key at postulantes) have the same date (which is field postulante_postulacion_fecha), if they do then return this result (Roberto), if not then it should not give me this result of Roberto (document number 71850071), have not been able to find by eye something like this (same date) in the database

Comment: Not helping at all. We need proper sample data, like [markdown tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) or `CREATE TABLE...INSERT...` statements. Maybe even construct a https://dbfiddle.uk as well, showing the issue. Images are no use, we can't copy them.

Comment: @Charlieface used some markdown tables please check it again, at the end I also added some example of same date on different postulante_id records for the expected result to happen (I think)

Comment: @Charlieface feel free to ask for anything else you might need, maybe sample data for when it should not return a result

Comment: After you've changed to a normal `JOIN`, what is wrong with your current query? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ca5dafcee974fa05852f09be533ad99f

Comment: It is so difficult, I am getting null values on miembro_documento, so I added a not null clause on the WHERE, and the query is working but it is not doing exactly how I need it to be, it is bringing me results that I not really need, I will try to explain in an EDIT

Comment: @Charlieface check edit please

Comment: Still unclear what it is you are trying to get to. Perhaps you need `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT pm.miembro_postulante) > 1` see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee86c6efbb3d877439efcd4c32959142

Comment: @Charlieface yes that did the job, the distinct pm.miembro_postulante with the count at the having, tyvm, post an answer and I can give you best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want a condition ensuring that the number of *distinct* `miembro_postulante` values per group is more than one.

After cleaning up your code by using modern join syntax, and removing redundant predicates, we can use `COUNT(DISTINCT`

```sql
SELECT
    pm.miembro_documento,
    p.postulante_postulacion_fecha, 
    COUNT(*)  
FROM 
    PostulantesMiembros pm
JOIN Postulantes p ON pm.miembro_postulante = p.postulante_id
WHERE pm.miembro_documento IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    pm.miembro_documento, p.postulante_postulacion_fecha 
HAVING  
    COUNT(DISTINCT pm.miembro_postulante) > 1;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9b1d0a1d37cfef62b3d8f02b35189e9f)

A possibly more efficient version compares the min and max.

```sql
SELECT
    pm.miembro_documento,
    p.postulante_postulacion_fecha, 
    COUNT(*)  
FROM 
    PostulantesMiembros pm
JOIN Postulantes p ON pm.miembro_postulante = p.postulante_id
WHERE pm.miembro_documento IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    pm.miembro_documento, p.postulante_postulacion_fecha 
HAVING  
    MIN(pm.miembro_postulante) <> MAX(pm.miembro_postulante);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE PostulantesMiembros (
  `miembro_id` INTEGER,
  `miembro_nombres` VARCHAR(7),
  `miembro_documento` INTEGER,
  `miembro_postulante` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO PostulantesMiembros
  (`miembro_id`, `miembro_nombres`, `miembro_documento`, `miembro_postulante`)
VALUES
  ('27224', 'Roberto', '71850071', '8283'),
  ('29658', 'Roberto', '71850071', '9042');

CREATE TABLE Postulantes (
  `postulante_id` INTEGER,
  `postulante_postulacion_fecha` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO Postulantes
  (`postulante_id`, `postulante_postulacion_fecha`)
VALUES
  ('8283', '2007-04-27 00:00:00.000'),
  ('9042', '2007-04-27 00:00:00.000');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT miembro_documento
     , postulante_postulacion_fecha
     , COUNT(*)
  FROM PostulantesMiembros pm
  JOIN Postulantes p
    ON pm.miembro_postulante = p.postulante_id
 GROUP BY miembro_documento, postulante_postulacion_fecha
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

| miembro_documento | postulante_postulacion_fecha | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 71850071 | 2007-04-27 00:00:00 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mCLczST7iA1CLPWkCdrq4F/1)

Comment: Hi thank you for the detailed answer, the query works but I still need more specific result, I will try to explain on an EDIT

Comment: Check EDIT I made on question please